# JQuery Line is not Executing

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm not sure why this `JQuery` line is not executing :

```
$('#Client').change(function ()...
```

My code is :

```
@model StockHoldings.Models.Investments

<head>
    <script src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    @*<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js" type='text/javascript'></script>*@
</head>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{ @Html.DropDownList("Client", ViewData["client"] as SelectList, "Select Client", new { id = "Client_ID", style = "width: 150px;" })<br />
    @*{ @Html.DropDownList("Fund", "Select Fund")};*@
        <select id="Fund" name="Fund" , style="width: 150px;"></select><br />
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PurchaseDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PurchaseDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PurchaseDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

}
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
<script type="text/jscript">
    $(document).ready(function () {    
        $('#Client').change(function ()
            {

             alert('here');

            $.getJSON('@Url.Action("ClientInvestmentsSince2", "Reports")', { id: $(#Client).val() }, function (data)
                //$.getJSON('@Url.Action("ClientInvestmentsSince2", "Reports")', { id:1 }, function (data)

            {
                var items = '<option>Select Fund</option>';
                $.each(data, function (i, fund)
                {
                    items += "<option value='" + fund.Value + "'>" + fund.Text + "</option>";
                })
                .fail(function (jqxhr, textStatus, errorMessage) { alert(errorMessage); });
                //assign the result to the Fund selectlist
                $('#Fund').html(items);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Any errors?  Please refer to: [Ask]. Please post a [MCVe].

Answer (score 0):

Your SELECT element's Id is `Client_ID`. But in your javascript code, you are binding the click event to an element with Id `Client`

Either change your jQuery selector to use the correct Id

```
$(function(){
  $('#Client_ID').change(function (){         
      var clientId = $(this).val();
      alert(clientId );  
      //use clientId for your ajax call     
  });      
})
```

Or use the the name attribute for your jQuery selector.

```
$(function(){
   $('SELECT[name="Client"]').change(function(){
      var clientId = $(this).val();
      alert(clientId );  
      //use clientId for your ajax call       
   });      
})
```

This should work assuming you do not have any other script errors in your page which is preventing this js code to execute.